# The notion api (Query a database) returns a 500 error

Tags: notion-api

I can't get more than 50 records from DB using Query a database api.

More specifically, the following
The following error occurs when the following is used as a request parameter

If page_size is 51 or more, a 500 api error occurs.
500 api error if filter or sort is used.
500 api error if next_cursor is used

The following is an error.

---

```
@notionhq/client warn: request fail {
  code: 'internal_server_error',
  message: 'Unexpected error occurred.'
}
/Users/yukiokamura/balance/corporate/notion/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/errors.js:162
        return new APIResponseError({
               ^

APIResponseError: Unexpected error occurred.
    at buildRequestError (/Users/yukiokamura/balance/corporate/notion/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/errors.js:162:16)
    at Client.request (/Users/yukiokamura/balance/corporate/notion/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/Client.js:347:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async load (/Users/yukiokamura/balance/corporate/notion/test.js:23:20) {
  code: 'internal_server_error',
  status: 500,
  headers: Headers {
    [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      date: [ 'Fri, 23 Jun 2023 03:55:04 GMT' ],
      'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
      'content-length': [ '101' ],
      connection: [ 'close' ],
      'x-powered-by': [ 'Express' ],
      etag: [ 'W/"65-MNTg8XqXYHKOgxGmrYud6AQ4G+w"' ],
      vary: [ 'Accept-Encoding' ],
      'cf-cache-status': [ 'DYNAMIC' ],
      'set-cookie': [
        '__cf_bm=7tu7DPPn9n9fAgGnifVYVLVOR4mMwVDxeSUxWBzLTQM-1687492504-0-AbeRCuELm1Lht65l7AXnHEC3eq2RvypE+7hQIwS3BWy7uYiP4o9YNIiJ7qntWM+mDGNL/+YFLkxhWFUn173dmqQ=; path=/; expires=Fri, 23-Jun-23 04:25:04 GMT; domain=.notion.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
      ],
      server: [ 'cloudflare' ],
      'cf-ray': [ '7db9cb149eda3469-NRT' ]
    }
  },
  body: '{"object":"error","status":500,"code":"internal_server_error","message":"Unexpected error occurred."}'
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve more than 50 items from the DB.